# rotate text/div 90 degrees (static)

Tags: jquery, css

Needing a cross browser method to rotate a div 90 degrees, and all elements within are rotated accordingly. This is for a static placement (not an animation).

Best practice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use CSS to rotate the contents of a div:

```
/* FF Chrome Opera etc */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
/* IE */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

**edit** Added Opera CSS

Comment: Only in browsers that support this, though.  A quick way to find this out is http://html5test.com/, look at the second category "Canvas".

Comment: @Steve Why would this be related to canvas? This is CSS 2D transforms http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms

Comment: Is CSS3 considered "cross-browser" yet?

Comment: I did find a jquery plugin that is cross browser because css3 is not cross browser.http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is stuck trying to implement this in IE8, try the following CSS:

```
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
-ms-writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE8 */
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It worked for me! :)